# How to click on the simpleAdapter listview to change the fragment and get the data?

Tags: java, android

I have to create a listview which can display more than two data included "eventName" and "date". I want to click the listview item on `ActivityFragment` which can change to `ActivityContentFragment`. Actually, The error pointed that "HashMap cannot be cast" and stop run application When I clicked the listview item .

**ActivityFragment**

```
private void displayArrayList(String jsonStr){

        String[] from = {"listView_eventName", "listView_date"};
        int[] to = {R.id.listView_eventName, R.id.listView_date};


        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), convertToＷordArrayList(jsonStr), R.layout.listview_activity, from, to);

        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ActivityInfo activityInfo =(ActivityInfo) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                ActivityContentFragment fragment = new ActivityContentFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("eventName", activityInfo.eventName());
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Json Handle**

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convertToＷordArrayList(String jsonStr){
    JSONObject jsonObject ;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    try{
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("article");

        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObjRow=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ActivityInfo activityInfo =new ActivityInfo();

            activityInfo.eventName =jsonObjRow.getString("eventName");
            activityInfo.date=jsonObjRow.getString("date");

            activityInfo.setEventName(jsonObjRow.getString("eventName"));


            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("listView_eventName", activityInfo.eventName);
            hm.put("listView_date", activityInfo.date);


            JSONArray jsonArray2=jsonObjRow.getJSONArray("content");

            for (int j=0;j<jsonArray2.length();j++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjRow2 = jsonArray2.getJSONObject(j);
                activityInfo.review=jsonObjRow2.getString("review");
            }
            arrayList.add(hm);
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

**ActivityInfo Class**

```
public class ActivityInfo implements Serializable {

    public String eventName;
    public String date;
    public String review;

    public void setEventName(String eventName){
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getEventName(){
        return this.eventName;
    }
}
```

**ActivityContentFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity_content, container, false);   

            activityInfo= (ActivityInfo)getArguments().getSerializable("eventName");

             TextView textView =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView textView2 =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            textView.setText(activityInfo.eventName);
            textView2.setText(activityInfo.date)

        return view;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change type of this to make types consistent:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> convertToＷordArrayList(String jsonStr){
```

to

```
private ArrayList<ActivityInfo> convertToActivityInfoList(String jsonStr){
```

Comment: In this case the SimpleAdapter wouldn't work, he need to create a custom adapter

Comment: If you must use SimpleAdapter, you can make ActivityInfo extends Map<String, String>

Comment: WHAT?! Are you joking? Activity doesn't need to extends Map<String, String>! Stop giving bad advice please

Comment: the SimpleAdapter wouldn't work, please give me other suggest.

Comment: @ Luca Nicoletti, please give me some other suggest.

Comment: @Luca Nicoletti , ActivityInfo is not Activity, right?

Comment: @AIMINPAN if you edit your comment, it's not on me :) You wrote Activity the first time.

Comment: @Luca Nicoletti , oh yes! I realized the typo in 1 minute and fixed it, didn't know you still caught it! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `convertToＷordArrayList(String jsonStr)` returns an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` but you're assigning the item of the list to a variable which is an `ActivityInfo`. You can't do this, you need to convert what is returned from that function into an `ActivityInfo`.

The list contains HashMaps. Create a function that from HashMap returns an `ActivityInfo` object:

```
private ActivityInfo convertHashMapToActivityInfo(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo =new ActivityInfo();
    activityInfo.eventName = map["listView_eventName"];
    activityInfo.date = map["listView_date"];
    activityInfo.review = map["listView_review"]; // be aware you're not adding this into the map in your code, so this would return null!!
    return activityInfo;
}
```

then in your `listView.setOnItemClickListener` you need to call this function like that:

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = 
    convertHashMapToActivityInfo(listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Comment: Just create above method from your suggest ?No need to change others ?

Comment: No, so you can keep using the simple adapter

Comment: @  Luca Nicoletti, I got the error "Array Type Expected" of the "map" on line 3 and I got the error "cannot not be applied" on "    convertHashMapToActivityInfo(listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
"